# Is there an on end event where I can free up drawable resources in android?

Tags: android, events

In my android app, I use Imageview's to show images. But I want to properly free it up when the activity ends. I read somewhere you can use `imgview.setImageDrawable(null);` to free it up. But I would like to do this when the activity ends. Is there some function like `on destroy` or `on end` that I can override so I can free it up there?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can do this in `onDestroy()`. How useful is this? No clue. Keep in mind that `onDestroy()` may or may not be called.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is `onDestroy` in `Activity`, but you don't need to null `Drawable`s like that unless you introduced a memory leak somewhere else in code.